# Why is a sum of skewed left distribution normal distributed according to the central limit theorem

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

The central limit theorem says that a sum of i.i.d. random variables is normal distributed. Now I have a large number of random variables (100000 responses to an item of a questionaire) but the distribution is skewed left. So with so many respondants I can even ask 1Million the distribution will not change.

So, maybe I do not understand it right, but should not (according to the central limit theorem) this distribution be normal?

Further I have read that

$$
S_n = X_1 + ... + X_n
$$
and

$$
Z_n = \frac{S_n - \mu n}{\sigma \sqrt(n)}
$$

Does that mean that every distribution that is changable to a normal distribution via linear transformation is normal distributued? (this should be almost everything).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does that mean that every distribution [...] is normal distributued?

Not not the distribution is normal, but the sum or mean of a lot of values drawn from that distribution tends to be drawn form a normal distribution.

A distribution by definition does not change whether you draw one sample, a million samples or $10^{10}$ samples. But the sum or the mean of the samples do not stem from the same distribution aus the samples.

Maybe a little example in `R` can help clear this up. A beta distribution with shape parameters 1 and 50 is far from a normal distribution. You can plot it using R and the command:

```
curve(expr = dbeta(x, 1, 50))
```

[image]>

Now let'S take 10000 samples from that distribution, each size of 100, and compute their sums. Now lets draw a histogram of these sums:

```
hist(replicate(10000, sum(rbeta(100, 1, 50))), breaks = 50)
```

[image: Histogram of sums of beta(1,50) distibuted samples]

you can easily see, how this is nearing normal distribution. Not the beta distribution becomes normal, but the distribution of the sums.

Answer (score 2):

The skewness decreases for the sum $Z_n = \frac{S_n - \mu n}{\sigma \sqrt(n)}$ when $n$ is increasing.

You have for first three central moments that

$$ \begin{array}{} 
\mu_1(Z_n) &=&  0 \\
\mu_2(Z_n) &=&  1  \\
\mu_3(Z_n) &=&  \frac{\mu_3(X)}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} 
\end{array}$$

this you could derive by using the [properties of cumulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Some_properties_of_cumulants) for which the first three relate to the central moments. You could derive similar relations for higher order moments (but more complicated) and end up with the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) which you could see as the vanishing of the cumulants with order above 2.